# 'Nil' error when calling models from root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called Museum and another model called Exhibtion. Museum is a parent of Exhibition.

I have created an adhoc controller in order to handle the root page.

routes file :

```
get 'welcome/index'
resources :museums

resources :museums do
   resources :exhibitions do
     resources :exhibitionimages
   end
   resources :museumimages
end

root 'welcome#index'
```

(please disregard museumimages and exhitionimages models)

**I am trying to show all exhibitions on the root page** as a table with links to show, edit, ...

here is the Welcome controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @exhibitions = Exhibition.all
  end
end
```

and the viewfile index.erb:

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Text</th>
<th>Start</th>
<th>End</th>
<th>Link</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>

<% @exhibitions.each do |exhibition| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= exhibition.title %></td>
    <td><%= exhibition.text %></td>
    <td><%= exhibition.start %></td>
    <td><%= exhibition.end %></td>
    <td><%= exhibition.linktoexhibition %></td>
    <td><%= exhibition.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', museum_exhibition_path(exhibition.museum, exhibition), method: :get  %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_museum_exhibition_path(exhibition.museum, exhibition), method: :get  %></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'destroy', museum_exhibition_path(exhibition.museum, exhibition), method: :delete  %></td>

  </tr>
```

Though i get an error with the links.

**It seems that the museum_id is not passed to the form link_to helpers where it appears as 'NIL' and fails the link creation.**
Those links work perfectly when used inside the museum controller (where the same table is shown with exhibitions belonging to the very parent)

Comment: can you check your data? it's possible that you have an exhibition that does not have a museum_id ? and is thus exploding when you try to fetch out the museum.

Comment: I was about to delete my post. This is correct ! Some exhibitions  have been created before the nesting of models had been done. And subsequently populated with 'Nil'. I thought my code had flaws again though. (I wasn't sure I could make a reference to parent as a method of child such as **child.parent**  ..) Many thanks

Comment: Post the error and post `rake routes`